Are there other ways we know of a massive star becoming a Black Hole other than the star going supernova?
Are Black Holes in the past, but also in the present, possibly formed by a process other than "very massive stars going supernova"?

asked also here without much success. interesting question though

Note, that there could also be direct collapse black holes that were never “massive stars”.

6 days ago, MIT reported the first evidence for direct collapse - Physicists discover first “black hole triple”

@mmesser314 Calling this an “evidence” would be an overstatement. They themselves call it a “suspicion” while in reality it is a speculation designed to attract attention to their otherwise unremarkable discovery.

@A.V.S. Since the OP is asking about the past and present, perhaps it is worth mentioning that direct collapse black holes cannot be formed today, because the universe is already too cold to keep the gas cloud from fragmenting into multiple stars instead of collapsing to a single black hole.
